# Custom print of object in C# Interactive

Tags: c#, .net, c#-interactive

Consider this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) class:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

When I evaluate and print such an object in *C# Interactive*, it looks like this:

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
Foo<string> { }
```

That's not useful. I'd like it to look like this:

```
Foo<string> { "bar" }
```

How do I do that?

I've tried overriding `ToString` like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Foo{typeof(T)} {{ {value} }}";
}
```

This doesn't produce quite what I'd like:

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
[Foo<System.String> { bar }]
```

There're at least three issues with this output:

1. The value is not in quotes. I'd like it to be `"bar"` instead of `bar`.
2. The type argument is displayed as `System.String` instead of `string`.
3. The entire value is surrounded by square brackets. This is the least of my concerns.

Is there a way to make C# interactive display an object with a custom format?

I know that I can add a public property to the class in order to display the value, but I don't want to do that because of encapsulation concerns. To be clear, though, here's what I mean:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }
}
```

This prints closer to what I'd like:

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
Foo<string> { Value="bar" }
```

but, as I wrote, I don't want to add a public property.

How do I get it to behave like the following?

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
Foo<string> { "bar" }
> new Foo<int>(42)
Foo<int> { 42 }
```

Notice that when using anything else than a string (e.g. an `int`), there should be no quotes.

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, while I don't know how to answer this, one avenue is to understand what the C# interactive is calling when evaluating an object. It looks like it loops through public properties/members (I am guessing using reflection) and pretty prints that, or calls ToString if it's overridden in the class.  Perhaps it offers a hook to replace this logic with something else. I quickly looked for something like this in the documentation but haven't found it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute?

Comment: @khellang I had, but apparently a bit too casual. I think this is the correct solution. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kristian Hellang suggests, this can be simply and easily addressed by adding a `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute to the class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ value }")]
public class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This addresses all concerns:

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
Foo<string>("bar")
> new Foo<int>(42)
Foo<int>(42)
> new Foo<DateTime>(new DateTime(2018, 4, 23))
Foo<DateTime>([23.04.2018 00:00:00])
```

The rendering doesn't use curly brackets, but rather the normal brackets indicated by the constructor, but I only find that appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute to customize the object print. Beside overriding `ToString()`, you can use any methods/properties in this attribute. For example:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{GetDebuggerDisplay(), nq}")]
public class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private string GetDebuggerDisplay()
    {
        var val = value is string ? "\"" + value + "\"" : value?.ToString();
        return $"Foo<{typeof(T).Name.ToLower()}> {{ {val} }}";
    }
}
```

This avoids having to override `ToString()`, or use a different implementation. Such as returning the string representation of `T value`.

You'll need to add a switch/case to transform class names such as `Int32` to `int`.

The `nq` part of the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute [removes the quotes around the value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2019#using-expressions-in-debuggerdisplay).

The result looks like:

```
> new Foo<string>("bar")
Foo<string> { "bar" }
```

For further reference, please check out the excellent blog post of Jared Parson about the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices/.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with overriding the `ToString()` like in your first attempt, then you can do whatever you like there. This gets you closer to what you want and you can modify it as you see fit:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string v = value is string ? $"\"{value}\"" : $"{value}";
    string t = typeof(T).Name.ToLower();
    return $"Foo<{t}> {{ {v} }}";
}
```

Comment: typeof(T).Name.ToLower() will not give you the built-in C# type for all types, e.g. typeof(int).Name.ToLower() wil return int32

Comment: @Krimson Yes, that's obvious, which is why I said *"This gets you closer to what you want and you can modify it as you see fit"*. Fixing the integral types (`int`, `short`, `long`, etc) is easy with a simple `switch` expanding what I did for `string` to include all primitive types. What's really difficult though is the non-primitive types like `int?`, `List<T>`, etc...